# Why does the coroutine break my app when using setOnTouchListener?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to call some code when the user touches the button. When the user stops pressing, the app should stop sending info to the server - chunks of audio. And I should use coroutines, I suppose. But the screen freezes and the app breaks.

```
    override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

                runBlocking {

                    var job : Job? = null

                    when (event?.action) {
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                            val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
                            val job = launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                                var nextPrintTime = startTime
                                var i = 0
                                while (isActive) { // cancellable computation loop
                                    // print a message twice a second
                                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= nextPrintTime) {
                                        println("job: I'm sleeping ${i++} ...")
                                        nextPrintTime += 500L
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                            println("main: I'm tired of waiting!")
                            job?.cancelAndJoin() // cancels the job and waits for its completion
                            println("main: Now I can quit.")
                        }
                        else ->
                            Log.i("else", "else")
                    }

                }


                return v?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: true
            }
        })
```

This happens when using the onTouch with MotionEvent, I suppose. What's wrong? What do I suppose to do?

Answer (score 1):

Never use `runBlocking` in an app. It's for testing or for the `main` function in native Java console apps with no GUI.

`runBlocking` defeats the purpose of using coroutines and blocks the thread it was called from, causing your asynchronous work to block the thread. In this case, since it is called from the main thread, it blocks the main thread, so your UI will freeze and it will be impossible for the ACTION_UP signal to ever be received.

To fix your current code, you should launch a coroutine from `lifecycleScope` instead of using `runBlocking`. Also, you shadowed the `job` variable inside your ACTION_DOWN section. You need to use your existing variable to be able to cancel it outside that scope.

```
override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    var job : Job? = null
    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            job = lifecycleScope.launch {
                var nextPrintTime = startTime
                var i = 0
                while (true) { // cancellable computation loop
                    yield()
                    // print a message twice a second
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= nextPrintTime) {
                        println("job: I'm sleeping ${i++} ...")
                        nextPrintTime += 500L
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                println("main: I'm tired of waiting!")
                job?.cancelAndJoin() // cancels the job and waits for its completion
                println("main: Now I can quit.")
            }
        }
        else -> Log.i("else", "else")
    }
}
```

However, your use case seems to be just starting or stopping something from this listener. I'm not sure it makes sense to use coroutines for that. Maybe your class that handles the uploading work would be using coroutines internally, but it doesn't necessarily have to be started or stopped using a suspend function.

Comment: I don't think this helped, the code is still non-suspending and has a busy-wait loop. i think a `yield()` within the loop would help. And of course, as you note, it shouldn't have the loop in the first place.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Good catch. Thanks. I edited it to use yield. I don’t think I would do it this way either since it’s still very busily sending Runnables to the main looper, but I don’t think this is the OP’s intended task anyway since it’s copied from the documentation example. A repeating action could use delay if it’s okay to drift over time to not be happening exactly twice a second.

Comment: I think it won't cause starvation because the handler must be dequeued in order to enqueue another event, which goes to the back of the queue. In the meantime any other events may be enqueued for processing. But it's a poor solution in any case. GUI apps allow very precise timing in order to support smooth animations/transitions, you can trigger an event on each screen frame.